# Agricolae, tapply, error: arguments must have same length

Tags: r, arguments, tapply

I am new to R and I am having issues moving forward with the data analysis. My Excel data has a lot of NA's and I tried troubleshooting this error. Here's my code if anyone can help, and a link to a sample of my data

```
file:///C:/Users/steph/Documents/DLI%20ANOVA%20Sample.htm
```

Some of my variables have 4 reps instead of all 8reps, so I have a lot of NA's in the excel file. I keep getting this error after I try `tapply`:

```
Error in tapply(X = data1$gi..m3., INDEX = data1$cultivar, FUN = mean,  : 
  arguments must have same length
```

```
library(agricolae)
data1=read.csv("DLI ANOVA Sample.csv", header=T, as.is=T)

#setting factors
block = as.factor(data1$block)
treatmentt = as.factor(data1$trt)
cultivar<-factor(data1$cv,c("CR", "LB","RF","RR","S","SNS","SNY","SSJ","YC"))
str(data1)

#Summary statistics
tapply(X = data1$growth.index, INDEX = data1$cultivar, FUN = mean, na.rm=T)
tapply(X = data1$growth.index, INDEX = data1$treatment, FUN = mean, na.rm=T)
```

```
data.frame':    288 obs. of  24 variables:
 $ block                                    : int  1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 1 1 ...
 $ trt                                      : chr  "HL-L" "HL-L" "HL-L" "HL-L" ..
 $ cv                                       : chr  "CR" "CR" "CR" "CR" ...
 $ rep                                      : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1 2 ...
 $ height                                   : int  23 20 25 19 23 19 22 19 19 24 
 $ growth.index                             : num  0.0221 0.0258 0.0276 0.0227 0.0209
 $ number.of.mature.fruit                   : int  34 30 35 34 28 25 40 24 12 16 ...
 $ mature.fruit.fw                          : num  163 163 186 152 169 ...
 $ number.of.immature.fruit                 : int  38 28 40 27 35 37 44 48 20 30 ...
 $ immature.fruit.fw                        : num  77.4 66.6 87.6 43.4 81.3 ...
 $ Total.number.of.fruit                    : num  72 58 75 61 63 62 84 72 32 46 ...
 $ Total.fruit.fw                           : num  241 230 273 195 250 ...
 $ Fruit.Water.Content..g.                  : num  NA 209 NA 176 NA ...
 $ Brix..                                   : num  4.9 NA 5.6 NA 4.7 NA 5.1 NA 5.6 NA ...
 $ pH                                       : num  4.17 NA 4.3 NA 4.1 ...
 $ EC.uS.mL                                 : num  4.46 NA 9.19 NA 8.24 ...
 $ X..citric.Acid                           : num  0.704 NA 0.397 NA 0.653 ...
 $ Sugar.Acid.Ratio                         : num  6.96 NA 14.11 NA 7.2 ...
 $ oedema.injury.level..1.6.                : int  3 3 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 ...
 $ Stomatal.conductance                     : num  NA 365 NA 422 NA ...
 $ spad                                     : num  NA NA NA 64.3 NA 65.5 NA 68.7 NA 55.6 ...
 $ Irrigation.Events                        : int  NA 14 NA 12 NA 13 NA 16 NA 13 ...
 $ WUE                                      : num  NA 0.00584 NA 0.00693 NA ...
 $ transpiration..g.H2O.lost..g.dry.biomass.: num  NA 117 NA 111 NA ...
```

Comment: You need to create `data1` and then use `dput(data1)` to provide data by pasting the results into your question. We have no access to your computer. Showing us `str(data1` would help since it is not clear that `cultivar` or `treatment` are variables that are located inside `data1`. Perhaps `INDEX=cultivar` would work for example.

Comment: Hi @dcarlson, I hope my edited post helps. Sorry for the frustration, I am very new to this and have no idea what I am doing.

Comment: So now we know that there is no variable called `data1$cultivar` but there is one called `cultivar`. Also there is no variable called `data1$treatment` but there is one called `treatmentt` so those should be the variables used with `INDEX=`.

Comment: @dcarlson now I get this error

```
 tapply(X = data1$growth.index., INDEX = cultivar, FUN = mean)
Error in tapply(X = data1$growth.index., INDEX = cultivar, FUN = mean) : 
  arguments must have same length
```

Comment: What is `length(data1$growth.index)` and `length(cultivar)`? If they do not agree, your list of the `cv` categories is probably missing something. Try `table(data1$cv)` and make sure all of the categories listed are in the one you are using when you create the factor with `c("CR", "LB","RF","RR","S","SNS","SNY","SSJ","YC")`. If you deliberately left some categories out, that is the problem.